# How to avoid X axis to display decimal values

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, charts, highcharts

I have a question about formatting my axis on highcharts. I want to display the ticks on the X axis to avoid decimals and display only whole numbers.

The current situation:

```
0
0.05
1
1.5
2
```

I want to display my number like this:

```
1
2
3
```

The Decimal number place should be left blank.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the same topic already exists, but can't find it, though. Anyway, there is a couple of solutions, two easiest:

- set [`allowDecimals`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.allowDecimals) to false
- set [`tickInterval`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickInterval) to 1

You can also play around with [formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter) and [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner).